# Docker, Copying image, error - ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image, docker-copy

i'm doing a tutorial in docker, and trying to copy a image from docker, and reference the index.hmtl file im my local file,
vinnyx05 -> is my login at docker, im running docker desktop.
in using Windows 11.
the code is:

```
PS C:\html> docker build -t vinnyx5/nginx-imersao13:latest . 
[+] Building 0.2s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                         0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 101B                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                            0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:latest                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:latest                                                                                         0.0s 
 => ERROR [2/2] COPY html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/                                                                                  0.0s 
------
 > [2/2] COPY html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/:
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM nginx:latest
   2 |
   3 | >>> COPY html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref ccf5a995-3d05-4517-a1ee-20291664f134::ljszgt44a3wte8c2sal6f54p2: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2559770106/html: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2559770106/html: no such file or directory
```

i dont know how to fix this, help please?
Thanks =)

im trying to do a copy of image, and edit de index.html locally

Comment: pls, post the Dockerfile

Comment: FROM nginx:latest

COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're running over a linux based terminal (like WSL). It seems to be a "windows" issue.

Answer (score 1):

Docker cannot find the file `html/index.html`.

Probably, in relation to your folder structure, you should copy the file like this:

```
COPY ./html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the right `context` folder when building image, especially in case of docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

You are building from inside the html folder with:

```
PS C:\html> docker build -t vinnyx5/nginx-imersao13:latest .
```

The build context in that command is `.` or the current directory.

You then attempt to copy the file `html/index.html` from that context to the image with:

```
COPY html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

For that to work, the file `C:\html\html\index.html` needs to exist (note the double `html` in the path).

To fix this, either change your context to be a directory higher (not recommended since you are working just under `c:\` and you don't want to copy the entire C drive to the docker temp directory which is frequently on the C drive). Or preferably fix the `COPY` command to reference a file that exists in your context, e.g.:

```
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your .dockerignore file, if it exists make sure that the file mentioned in the error message is not present in this file.

Answer (score 0):

I was on Linux when I got this error. I was building from a bash script located in a different directory. The solution was to ensure that when you invoke the `docker build` command, you are invoking it from the location of your `Dockerfile`.

Say the Dockerfile had an entry such as

```
COPY ./assets/file-to-copy ./
```

And a structure as follows

```
├── image-foo
│    ├── Dockerfile
│    └── assets
│         └──file-to-copy
└──build-script.sh
```

To build from the command line, make sure that you are in the `image-foo` directory.

```
cd image-foo
docker build -t foo .
```

Or if using a build script you do something like

build-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# pre build stuff

cd ./image-foo
docker build -t foo .

# post build stuff
```